# How to fill encrypted columns in database using SqlBulkCopy?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, encryption, sqlbulkcopy

I'm using `SqlBulkCopy` and `System.Data.Datatable` to insert data into my database. I'm doing something like this:

```
var table = new DataTable();

// Creating table schema
var newRow = table.NewRow();
newRow["FirstName"] = Parser.Parse(values[0])
newRow["LastName"] = Parser.Parse(values[1])
...
newRos["SSN"] = //here I need to encrypt by db certificate value[5] before set it to this row value
```

And simple copy to db code:

```
using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, transaction))
{
    bulkCopy.BatchSize = 100;
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Member";
    try
    {    
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
        connection.Close();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Of course I can set encrypted column later using a stored procedure in the database, but I want to do this in one transaction. Is it possible to encrypt `string` value using my certificate from the database in code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you use the value to encrypt it in your C# code? why you can't add to the DataTable the value after its encrypted?

Comment: @Shahar I have a master key, certificate with some algorithm in db. Are you sure that data encrypted from the code will be compatible with data decrypted using db procedure after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see this, you can choose one of the following options (which should be both easy to implement):

**Do the encryption in your C# code**

Since you have all the data there, you can make the encryption there using .NET Framework relevant classes. You can test it and make sure you get the same result.

**Use AFTER INSERT trigger**

After adding the value, you'll modify and add the encrypted data. The trigger will be part of the same transaction. Just use CREATE TRIGGER statement to create a new trigger, check if the value is NULL and then put the encrypted value using SQL statements.

For Example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[myTrigger]
   ON  [dbo].[Members] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE Members
    SET [EncryptedSSN] = EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('SSN_Key'), inserted.SSN)
    FROM inserted 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Members On inserted.id = Members.id
END
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If i go by the second way, do you mean something like this?:
`CREATE TRIGGER trigAddMember
ON dbo.Member
FOR INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [dbo].[Member]
DECLARE @NewSSN VARCHAR(100)
SELECT @NewSSN =(SELECT SSN FROM INSERTED)
SET [EncryptedSSN] = EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('SSN_Key'), i.SSN)
UPDATE [dbo.Member]
SET i.SSN = NULL
END`?

Comment: @user3818229 i think you forgot the UPDATE statement at the end. you should also add something like UPDATE dbo.Member SET EncryptedSSN=@NewSSN FROM inserted INNER JOIN dbo.Members ON inserted.ID = members.ID

Comment: oh sorry, didn't see it at first. yes, but you should ass WHERE to the UPDATE clause.

Comment: Could you edit your answer with adding `sql statement` to make code more readable please?

Comment: Note, using Shahar's method you likely will want to add a `, SSN = null` in the `SET` so the unencrypted copy is not saved after the transaction commits. However depending on why you are encrypting the SSN (for example HIPPA laws) this method may violate whatever compliance you are trying to do because it is possible to see the unencrypted SSN at rest (even if it is only for a brief moment).